# WSO2: attempting to test a REST method, but it is returning a '404 Not Found' error

Tags: wso2, swagger, swagger-ui, wso2-api-manager, .net-core-3.1

I am using WSO2 API Manager to publish my WebApi Gateway, which is connected to my REST services. However, when attempting to test my GET service, it returns a 404 Not Found error. My Gateway is built using .NET Core 3.1 and uses Swagger version 2.0. I am unsure whether the issue lies with WSO2, Swagger, or .NET Core 3.1. Can anyone assist me in resolving this issue? It is worth noting that my GET service test in the Swagger page 'swagger/index.html' is successful. I have attached the WSO2 and Swagger files, as well as my startup code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To help you figure out the issue, can you check/provide below details?

- I believe you have the REST service hosted locally. What have you configured as the WSO2 API's endpoint URL, API context and API version ?
- Can you invoke the REST service directly (without going through WSO2 GW) using cURL/postman etc ?
- Have you deployed the API ?

[PS : I am adding this as an answer because I do not have permission to add comments yet, sorry about that]

Comment: Thank you for response. The version of WSO2 currently being used is 4.1.0, and while I am able to invoke my APIs using both Postman and Swagger UI, I am encountering issues when attempting to do so with WSO2.

Comment: What have you defined as the endpoint URL of this API ? Is it `http://localhost:45356` ?